# Fetch tagged photos from instagram. Only getting my posts. I am sharing my demo code which is written in html

Tags: reactjs, instagram

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stevenschobert/instafeed.js@2.0.0rc1/src/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userFeed = new Instafeed({
get:'tagged', // userId: '623597756', //clientId: 'Client', target: 'instafeed-container', accessToken: 'accessToken', resolution: 'standard_resolution', sortBy: 'most-recent', limit: 8, template: '

{{username}}

{{caption}}

', templateBoundaries: ['{{','}}'],
}); userFeed.run();
```

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what is your problem, what you have already tried.

Comment: In reactjs application, I want to fetch the "tagged" photos from instagram. I have shared my code. Now with this I only able fetch "post" photos. Please explain me what to do? Thanks in advance.